# Can I use logistic regression from individual-level survey data to make predictions at an aggregate level?

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, aggregation

I have a logistic regression model that predicts the likelihood of an individual getting PTSD after a flood based on their race and gender. The regression is based on a survey of individual flood victims. Simplifying for the sake of this question, let's say that the variables are:

```
race: {1=Black, 0=White}
gender: {1=Female, 0=Male}
PTSD: {1=Yes,0=No}
```

I would like to use the results of this regression to predict the number of cases of PTSD in a region affected by a flood, but for each region the only data I have is the total population affected, the percent of that population that is Black, and the percent of the population that is female. Is there a way that I can calculate the expected number of cases of PTSD in the region based on this data?

The only way I can think to do this is to calculate the probability of PTSD for all four possible combinations of gender and race, and then use the population data to estimate the number of people in each group. This is simple enough for the case of having only two independent variables, but if I add more predictor variables, the process of calculating the probability for each combination becomes tedious.

I know that I can't simply multiply the regression coefficient for each variable by their percent of the total population, but I feel like there should be some way to simply calculate the total expected number of cases from the population proportions.

Comment: I don't see why not apply it to aggregated data, its predictive power cannot be that good anyways on individual level

Comment: I am trying to apply it to the aggregated data, but I'm not sure how to apply logistic regression model that was calculated from individual level data.

Comment: First, you should validate the model. It's hard to imagine that it's possible to predict accurately whether a flood victim will get PTSD just from their race and gender.

Comment: Then if you are happy to proceed, you can create a "grid" of potential flood victims by enumerating all possible combinations of predictors: X = {(female,black), (female,white), (male,black), (male,white)} and use the model to estimate the probability Pr{Y=1|X} for each combination of predictors. Then multiply Pr{Y=1|X} * #{X}. This approach generalizes to more covariates in an obvious way.

Comment: @dipetkov Yes, the actual model also includes information about the level of home damage and other flood impacts, but I wanted to simplify the problem for the question.